# Find data on a given day using BETWEEN

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a MS SQL 2008 DB table with column like this:

```
Date

2012-07-02 18:34:44.487
2012-07-02 18:34:44.480
2012-07-02 18:34:44.193
2012-07-02 18:34:44.193
```

When I do

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-07-02' AND '2012-07-02'
```

I get nothing.

What can I do to get all of the results above as they fall between the two dates.

Answer (score 5):

one way

```
   Select * from table1 where Date >= '2012-07-02' and Date < '2012-07-03'
```

this is also safer than between because with between you would also get the midnight value for the 3rd, see [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

Comment: +1 Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `dateadd`

```
Select * 
from table1 
where Date between '2012-07-02' and dateadd(d,1,'2012-07-02')
```

MSDN Docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Roughly, the reason for this is SQL treats string dates such as this example as midnight of the given date. So what you're really asking is `between midnight of 2012-07-02 and midnight of 2012-07-03`

Comment: be aware that it will grab the value at midnight 2012-07-03 with the between syntax, see here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select * from table1 where CONVERT(Date,Date)='2012-07-02'
```

Comment: This is very bad in terms of performance since it can't seek the index because of the conversion you are doing on the column

Comment: @SQLMenace that isn't true in this case - SQL Server actually has an optimization here that still allows an index to be used. But to avoid confusion I would really stop naming columns with keywords, because this convert just looks funny.

Comment: Aaron, true....I forgot about it..I even blogged about it http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/converting-columns-to-date-from-datetime-2008  getting old I guess :-)